# Blazor Server App, How can I bind my local file to the InputFile Component without browse

Tags: asp.net, .net, input, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm making a bulletin board with a blazer.
A post consists of a title, content, and a file, but it was successful to register it including the file.

But when I click on the post again and go to the details, I don't know how to bind the file back to the InputFile Component.
I checked that the file exists locally, but I think I just need to import it and bind it.. This is not easy ㅜㅜ

Could you possibly teach me?
I'm really, really grateful.. because of you

Should I access the component with @ref?
Or do I have to bind the file again with the IBrowserFile Interface?

It's frustrating.. Please let me know.

Environment is Blazor server App .Net 6

[my InputFile Component that i want to rebind file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BccS.png)

Comment: I don't know if this is possible because the input file is only supposed to be filled by user for security reasons. However, you can create a component that you display only when a path for the file exists and show the relevant information (with some kind of button to show again the input file to change the file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you're using `InputFile` as a kind of *storage* for the file, which is NOT what it's for.

`InputFile` is there to accept a file from the user, and allow you to upload it to the server.

You'll need to decide how to store it on the server side - this is really dependent on how you store the posts. If the post can accept a binary object you can store it there by reading the stream from the `InputFile`. You will probably also want to store the filename and possibly the `ContentType` as well in your post, if you want to allow a user to download from the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the file path as value using **@bind-value**. But it is not visible.